I have not been able to change security permissions on a laptop that I am the administrator of, could Bitdefender be the cause of the issue?
I have not been able to change security permissions on a laptop that i am the administrator of. Could Bitdefender be the cause of the issue?
I am running windows 10 Home on a Lenovo laptop, and have been wanting to share my drives and folders with my main HP Pavilion DV7 laptop, running windows 10 Professional Edition, but have been unable to. First when I click on my HP Laptop it says I must log into my account. It will not accept my windows password. So I work on trying to change the share and permissions on the Lenovo laptop.
I can enable sharing, but not security permissions. According to Microsoft until I change the security permissions I do not have full access to my HP Pavilion DV7 laptop. Each time I try to change security settings I get error messages.

Windows Home editions are limited.

@ChanganAuto - In what way? How NTFS permissions work on Home and Professional are identical.


Sharing a root drive might not be possible. 2. Sharing a folder should be simple, selecting Properties -> Sharing in Windows Explorer. You might try Share... with specific users, or Advanced Sharing. What have you tried?


What folder are you talking about exactly? Provide the ACL for the folder.

Share permissions and authentication are entirely unrelated to the underlying filesystem (ie. NTFS).

@Ramhound I'm probably mistaken but I think there's some difference in network shares. I don't remember the last time I used a Home edition though.

@ChanganAuto - What the author is attempting to do there is no difference
